# SELinux: How do you give access to only few processes to a /mnt/foo directory?

Tags: mount, selinux

I am having so much trouble trying to make only very few processes allowed access for a specific mounted directory.

Here are some of the questions for why I'm getting so lost. Assume that the mounted directory is called `/mnt/foo`, and the process I want to allow is `/bin/proc_a` and `/bin/proc_b`.

1. Do I need to create a custom type for `/mnt/foo`?
2. Do I need to create a custom domain for `/bin/proc_a`?
3. Can I have `/bin/proc_a` and `/bin/proc_b` to have different permissions if they are both allowed access? (For example, `proc_a` only can see the list of files inside `/mnt/foo` while `proc_b` can also write to a file in the directory)
4. If SELinux happens to be off, then is it possible for the default action to have no processes have any access to `/mnt/foo`?
5. What happens when I unmount at `/mnt/foo`?